# Scroll view does not scroll - Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, scrollview

I can't make a ScrollView properly scrolling.
I can scroll through the page but the scrollView itself not showing and it always cut off the content on the bottom.
The buttons portion is being cut off in portrait orientation, and not scrolling at all in the  landscape orientation.

Here is my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
tools:context=".signUp.SignUpFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".signUp.SignUpFragment">


        <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutCompat"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/signup_logo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="140dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/logo"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:hint="@string/name"
                android:paddingTop="16dp">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/signup_name_show"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLines="1" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:hint="@string/nick_name"
                android:paddingTop="16dp">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/signup_nickname_show"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLines="1" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:hint="@string/email"
                android:paddingTop="16dp">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/signup_email_show"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLines="1" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:hint="@string/password"
                android:paddingTop="16dp">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/signup_password_show"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:maxLines="1" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:hint="@string/verifypassword"
                android:paddingTop="16dp">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/signup_verifypass_show"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:maxLines="1" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


        </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/signup_profilepic_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:text="Profile picture"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayoutCompat" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/signup_cancel_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:backgroundTint="#7b9abe"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/signup_save_btn"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/signup_camera_btn" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/signup_save_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="#7b9abe"
            android:text="Sign Up"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/signup_cancel_btn"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/signup_cancel_btn" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/signup_camera_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/signup_profilepic_tv"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayoutCompat" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/signup_gallery_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/signup_camera_btn"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayoutCompat" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

My device:

[image: my device]

Thank you!!!

Comment: which theme using in your activity?

Comment: @tj2611 - it's a fragment not an activity.

Comment: please try Nested ScrollView

Comment: @tj2611 still the same :\

Comment: please add this one into your scrollview android:fitsSystemWindows="true" and try again, if still same problem try android:layout_height="wrap_content" to constraintlayout

Answer (score 0):

end of code write
</scrollView> and remove

```
fillViewport = “true”
```

Comment: I wrote it in my code( didn't copy it properly, sorry ).. so it's not the problem :(

Comment: OK! try this, (remove -> fillViewport = “true”)

Comment: Thank you but it's still the same

Comment: use this [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/175xeR9WcFeOUgLKko7qBuyFFYyND7XWk/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

This Is Not A Problem. It Working Fine In Portrait And Landscape.

Comment: I tried it on differnet emulators, and unfortunately it still cut off the content on the bottom.. (  as you can see in the picture - the buttons cut off)